# How to save a "mutableListOf" using TinyDB?

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

I am trying to use TinyDB from Github to save a list (mustableListOf), however when I try to save a string to the List, it puts an error on the 2nd parameter.

```
val tinydb = TinyDB(this)
    var todoList = mutableListOf(
        Todo("Write your first TODO statement", false)
    )

    val adapter = TodoAdapter(todoList)
    binding.rvTodos.adapter = adapter
    binding.rvTodos.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    binding.btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
        val title = binding.etTodo.text.toString()
        val todo = Todo(title, false)
        todoList.add(todo)
        //puts an error on the "mutableListOf(todoList)"
        tinydb.putListString("TodoList", mutableListOf(todoList))
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(todoList.size - 1)
    }
```

How could I resolve this?

Github TinyDB Link: https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

Updated code: however when the app is launched on my phone, the app keeps stopping. It only works the first time when nothing is stored in TinyDB. It doesn't put an error on the 2nd parameter anymore, but I feel like it's not storing/working in its intended way. Thanks.

```
val tinydb = TinyDB(this)

    var todoList = mutableListOf(
        Todo("Write your first TODO statement", false)
    )
    // line below is to get the list and set it to recyclerview; however app keeps stopping when invoked
    tinydb.getListObject("TodoList", Todo::class.java)
    val adapter = TodoAdapter(todoList)
    binding.rvTodos.adapter = adapter
    binding.rvTodos.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    binding.btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
        val title = binding.etTodo.text.toString()
        val todo = Todo(title, false)
        todoList.add(todo)
        //changed to putListObject
        tinydb.putListObject("TodoList", arrayListOf(todoList))
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(todoList.size - 1)
    }
```

Comment: `todoList` is a list of objects (instances of `Todo` class) and `putListString` method sounds like a method storing list of strings. Have you tried to use `putListObject` instead?

Comment: @PawelWoroniecki I changed "putListString" to "putListObject", but the recycler view (rvTodos) will not show the changes when the app is relaunched. Instead, it will just crash.

Comment: Why does it crash? Do you have any logs? It seems that the issue is probably with implementation of adapter for your recycler view and not with TinyDB.